# blazor validation AFTER valid submit

Tags: validation, blazor

In a simple form I have two input fields. I use the [Requered] attribute to validate the input.

If the input is valid, HandleValidSubmit is called.
I would now like to carry out my own validation here. For example, whether an entry already exists in the database, etc.

How can I add validation messages within HandleValidSubmit that will then be shown to me in ?

I've already tried using a ValidationMessageStore, but the message doesn't appear.

Here my code. Model user is missing, to complex for here..

```
<EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" Context="_editContext">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Benutzername</label>
    <InputText id="username" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@user.Name" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Name)" />
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Nachname</label>
    <InputText id="password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@user.Nachname" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Nachname)" />
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrieren</button>


 < /EditForm>



@@code {
    private UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    private ValidationMessageStore _validationMessageStore;
    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _editContext = new EditContext(user);
    _validationMessageStore = new
 ValidationMessageStore(_editContext);
}

private void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    //Just for Testing
    _validationMessageStore.Add(() => user.Nachname, "Der Nachname ist erforderlich");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `OnValidSubmit` then validation has already taken place before the method is called.

You need to run validation manually and add your own validation process to it.  The following one page demo shows you how to do that.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="username">User Name</label>
        <InputText id="username" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@user.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Name)" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <InputText id="password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@user.Password" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Password)" />
    </div>

    <div class="text-end mb-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.HandleSubmit>Register</button>
    </div>

</EditForm>

@code {
    private UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    private ValidationMessageStore _validationMessageStore = default!;
    private EditContext _editContext = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(user);
        _validationMessageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(_editContext);
    }

    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        if (await this.Validate())
        {
            // valid so do your valid stuff   
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> Validate()
    {
        // run the standard Validation
        var valid = _editContext.Validate();
        // clear our custom store
        _validationMessageStore.Clear();
        // Fake a database async call to check if the user exists
        await Task.Delay(100);
        //Just for Testing trip validation
        if (true)
        {
            // log message to store and notify the edit context
            _validationMessageStore.Add(() => user.Password, "Not Complex Enough");
            _editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public class UserEntity
    {
        [Required] public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required] public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you very much.
I found another way to do is outside of HandleValidSubmit (see my own Answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Your code shown works as expected for me. However i paste my full testset maybe u had something different in to model or in the page. I could only guess how the model looks like.

index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp8.Data

<EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" Context="_editContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Benutzername</label>
        <InputText id="username" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@user.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Name)" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Nachname</label>
        <InputText id="password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@user.Nachname" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Nachname)" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrieren</button>

    <ValidationSummary/>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    private ValidationMessageStore _validationMessageStore;
    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(user);
        _validationMessageStore = new
        ValidationMessageStore(_editContext);
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        //Just for Testing
        _validationMessageStore.Add(() => user.Nachname, "Der Nachname ist erforderlich");
    }
}
```

UserData

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace BlazorApp8.Data
    {
        public class UserEntity
        {
            [Required]
            [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Identifier too long (16 character limit).")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Nachname { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a way myself to "hook into" the standard validation.

In "OnInitialized" I add Context and MessageStore. I also add my own routine to the "myContext.OnValidationRequested" event.

In this routine I can run my tests and add my error messages to the validation process!

```
 protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        meinEditContext = new EditContext(User);
        meinMessageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(meinEditContext);
        meinEditContext.OnValidationRequested += OnValidateReuqested;
    }


private void OnValidateReuqested(Object sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        meinMessageStore.Clear();
        if (User.Vorname == "Alex")
        { 
            meinMessageStore.Add(() => User.Vorname, "So ein Murx");
            meinEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }
    }
```

To do this I had to change in Blazor EditForm:

```
<EditForm  OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" EditContext="meinEditContext" Context="_editContext">
```

Here is the entire page. Note: I'm using Developers Express components here. But that doesn't change the principle.

```
@page "/test"


@using *secret, sorry*.EntityClasses;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


<EditForm  OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" EditContext="meinEditContext" Context="_editContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    @meineMeldung
    <DxFormLayout Data="User" ItemUpdating="@((pair) => OnItemUpdating(pair.Key,pair.Value))">
      <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="VIP" ColSpanMd="6">
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Vorname" Field="User.Vorname"/>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Nachname" Field="User.Nachname"/>
    </DxFormLayoutGroup>
    </DxFormLayout>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrieren</button>
</EditForm>



    @code {
    
        public class UserModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Vorname ist nötig")]
            public string Vorname { get; set; }
    
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nachname ist nötig")]
            public string Nachname {get; set; }
        }
    
        public string meineMeldung = "";
        private UserModel User = new();
        private ValidationMessageStore meinMessageStore;   
        private EditContext meinEditContext;**
    
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            meinEditContext = new EditContext(User);
            meinMessageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(meinEditContext);
            meinEditContext.OnValidationRequested += OnValidateReuqested;
        }
    
        private void OnValidateReuqested(Object sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            meinMessageStore.Clear();
            if (User.Vorname == "Alex")
            { 
                meinMessageStore.Add(() => User.Vorname, "So ein Murx");
                meinEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            }
        }    
    
        void OnItemUpdating(string fieldName, object newValue)
        {  //Only necessary because of DevExpress-Components
            if (fieldName == "User.Vorname")
                User.Vorname = newValue.ToString();
            else User.Nachname = newValue.ToString();
        }
    
    
        private void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
            meineMeldung = "Valid Submit!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well done.  I kept my answer simple, but you've taken the next step in building custom validation.